# interpretation of interaction effects in a Cox-regression

Tags: r, interaction, statistical-significance

I am attempting to interpret results of my R output, especially interaction effects.

My analysis includes several models (2 of them shown below), at which I always have a metric Variable (in the examples shown below Inf_E, representing inflation) and a dummy-variable. So basically I try to examine whether the dummy variable moderates the effect of inflation for earlier termination of my Y.

```
##Example 1:

cox_prop <- coxph(Surv(Duration, termination) ~ Dummy_Var*Inf_E, 
                  data = daten)

summary(cox_prop)

                    coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z  Pr(>|z|)    
Dummy_Var       0.624281  1.866903 0.190427 3.278  0.00104 ** 
Inf_E           0.017425  1.017578 0.004429 3.934 8.35e-05 ***
Dummy_Var:Inf_E 0.047198  1.048330 0.020791 2.270  0.02320 * 



##Example 2:

cox_prop2 <- coxph(Surv(Duration, termination) ~ Dummy_Var2*Inf_E,
                  data = daten)

summary(cox_prop2)

                      coef exp(coef)  se(coef)      z  Pr(>|z|)    
Dummy_Var2        0.201798  1.223601  0.142189  1.419 0.155834    
Inf_E             0.031516  1.032018  0.009576  3.291 0.000998 ***
Dummy_Var2:Inf_E -0.018284  0.981882  0.010707 -1.708 0.087712 .
```

Concerning the output and the interpretation of the interaction term I have some questions:

1. Do interaction effects in Cox-regression work any different from normal linear regression effects and thus do you interpret them differently? (as you simply multiply the two Variables I guess the basic mechanism is the same)
2. I would assume, "Dummy_Var:Inf_E" means: If Dummy_Var takes the value 1, an increase in Inf_E by 1% leads to an increased hazard of early termination by 1.048%. Is this correct? If so, then I would further assume, as 1.048 is larger than 1.017 (just Inf_E), the dummy variable is increasing the effect of Inf_E. Is this correct as well?
3. In example number 2, Dummy_Var2 has no significant influence on its own but in interaction, the effect is at least slightly significant to alpha = 10%. Although it is not significant alone, I can still make statements about the interaction effect, like in the example above, right?
4. Example number 2 is also interesting due to the fact, that the interaction shows a coef below 0/ exp(coef) below 1, so it somewhat means a decline in the hazard. I would interpret the output like that: Dummy_Var2 and Inf_E both both lead to earlier terminations, however, when taken together the effect turns around. If Dummy_Var2 = 1, an increase in Inf_E decreases the hazard of termination, correct?

I know it is quite a long text but i would really appreciate your help, otherwise I will be quite lost :)

(If anything did not become clear let me know, English is not my native language, yet I hope it was comprehensible)